# SQL -Find and Replace the value in the table

Tags: sql

I have a table in my database. It contains 35 columns and 150 rows. Some of its values are 0. How can I replace these 0 with the character '-' ?

Comment: Is it for SQL Server?

Comment: Whether all the 35 column are having same datatype ?

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? what data types are the columns? do you want to actually change the data in the table or just display `-` instead of `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `UPDATE` to do this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1 = '0' THEN '-' ELSE col1 END,
col2 = CASE WHEN col2 = '0' THEN '-' ELSE col2 END,
col3 = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Column1,'0','-'),REPLACE(Column2,'0','-'), REPLACE(Column3,'0','-')etc..
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```